# Matching each unique pokemon with a unique move

Tags: graphs, matching

**Background:**

- There are 832 unique Pokemon in the Pokemon universe, and
- There are 728 fighting moves that the Pokemon can collectively learn.
- No Pokemon can learn to do every fighting move, and some Pokemon can only learn one.
- The average Pokemon can learn between 10-30 fighting moves , and
- Most fighting moves can be learned by multiple Pokemon.

**Challenge:**

I want to match as many unique Pokemon to one unique move. These are one-to-one matches.

**Example with U.S. presidents:**

- Name: Clinton, Moves: Democratify, Impeachify
- Name: Bush, Moves: Republicanify
- Name: Obama, Moves: Democratify, Healthcarify
- Name: Trump, Moves: Republicanify, Impeachify

**Example solution that matches the highest number** (in this case, all of them)

- Clinton-Democratify
- Bush-Republicanify
- Obama-Healthcarify
- Trump-Impeachify

**Summary:** 
What's an algorithm I could use to get the most potential matches of unique Pokemon to unique move?

**Caveat:** 
I'm just a regular guy, no computer science background, and a fuzzy memory of what I learned in my high school calculus class, and a VERY basic understanding of graph theory... so bonus points if you explain it simply enough for me to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your description of the problem is not super clear. I can guess that you're looking at a **maximum bipartite matching problem**. Which by the way, can also be viewed as a degenerate case of **maxflow problem**. Both problems are classic, you should have no problem finding resources on them. [For example, this.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-bipartite-matching/)

[image: maximum bipartitie matching example graph]

[image: maxflow example graph]

Comment: Yep!  This is what I was looking for, thanks for pushing me in the right direction!